# Are there reputation or frequency thresholds for "warning" messages?

Tags: discussion, reputation, self-answer, warnings

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442870/proving-p-leftrightarrow-q-landq-leftrightarrow-r-top-leftrightarrow-r) is a question I posted not long ago. It wasn't particularly well-received (-1), but I finally got around to working out the problem some more and decided to post my answer in case anyone else cared to see. However, I got the following message before posting:
[image]

I found this to be somewhat odd since 1) I've answered another one of my own [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117412/proving-forall-a-in-mathbbzm-in-mathbbz-to-am-equiv-am-phim)s before, and 2) my reputation right now is just above 13k (not particularly high but high enough to indicate that I'm a frequent user/contributor of/to this site).

My question concerns how these different "warnings" or pop-ups are triggered. I recall, when I first joined, having a pop-up before I made a comment, before I asked a question, etc. Does anyone have any knowledge of how/when these different pop-ups/warnings are triggered and whether or not it has anything at all to do with frequency (e.g., having answered 1 or more of your own questions, made several comments, etc.) or reputation (e.g., no pop-ups for users with >20k rep)?

Comment: I get this one too (rep > 42K), and I'm not answering own questions often, so I guess it's universal. This form of the dialog appears to be new; previously there was just a standard browser confirmation pop-up.

Comment: I have added (self-answer) tag, since you speak this type of warning in the most of your post. If your question is intended to be about all types of warnings and you thing this tag will distract from this, feel free to remove the tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for adding the tag--I wasn't sure the best tag(s) to use other than discussion so you and/or others can feel free to add what they deem necessary. I was largely puzzled by the self-answer prompt, but now I wonder what other prompts await...

Comment: There is a 2+ year old feature request on meta.se for removing this warning under certain circumstances (_e.g._, user rep, or having the [Self-Learner](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge). So far no official work from SE. [Can the “Are you sure you want to answer your own question” dialog be removed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188285).

Answer (score 2):

In general, I don't believe so - that is, I think in general the posting history of the user (including reputation and posting frequency) is not taken into account when deciding whether to show these popup messages. But things like the notification reminding you to vote on questions, which obviously would be meaningless if the user's voting history were not considered, are of course exceptions.

I'm not sure of a source to point to, other than those brought up in the comments ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188285/can-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-answer-your-own-question-dialog-be-removed)).